# How can I keep my two sections on the same line?

Tags: html, css

So I'm working on a website design where two sections stand right next to each other, but for some reason one section goes under the other one. Can someone help me find the problem? Thanks!

HTML code:

```
<section id="sec1">
  <img src="https://tse1.mm.bing.net/th?&id=OIP.Mbd6b4f30000f7e872ca4c55c2cedd6fao0&w=300&h=215&c=0&pid=1.9&rs=0&p=0&r=0" id="img1">
  <h6 class="bodytext">Watershed Definition</h6>
  <p class="bodytext">A ridge or area of land that separates waters flowing to different rivers, basins, or seas</p>
</section>
<section id="sec2">
  <img src="http://www.nature-education.org/estuary.gif" id="img1">
  <h6 class="bodytext">Estuary Definition</h6>
  <p class="bodytext">An arm or inlet of the sea at the lower end of a river or body of water.</p>
</section>
```

CSS code:

```
#sec1 {
background-color: #75c776;
width: 400px;
height: 550px;
margin-left: 300px;
margin-top: 40px;
border-radius: 5px;
border-style: solid;
clear: right;
}
#sec2 {
background-color: #75c776;
width: 400px;
height: 550px;
margin-left: 800px;
margin-top: 40px;
border-radius: 5px;
border-style: solid;
clear: left;
}
```

Comment: use `display: inline` or `float: left`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be trying to float them (from your use of clear: left/right)?

You don't have float set though...

If you float them both left, then clear right on the second only, that should work. They only appear on top of each other if there's not enough horizontal space then.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code You will get Solution :)

```
#sec1 {
background-color: #75c776;
width: 400px; 
height: 550px;
margin-left: 300px;
margin-right:50px;
margin-top: 40px;
border-radius: 5px;
border-style: solid;
float:left;
}
#sec2 {
background-color: #75c776;
width: 400px;
height: 550px;
margin-top: 40px;
border-radius: 5px;
border-style: solid;
float:left;
}
```

[image]